# Proof that $\exists \space a, b, c, \in \mathbb{N} (a,b,c: (a\neq b\neq c)\land (a^2 + b^2 = c^2))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Proof that $\exists \space a, b, c, \in \mathbb{N} (a,b,c: (a\neq b\neq c)\land (a^2 + b^2 = c^2))$

---

Today my teacher gave me homework to proof:
 $$\not \exists\space a, b, c \in \mathbb N (a,b,c: (a \neq b \neq c)\land(a^3  + b^3 = c^3))$$

As far of now, I'm just fimilar with elementry algebra. So, my way was to proof that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ exist (see question.) And I'll use the same method to produce a very informal proof that $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$ doesn't exist!

My try:

$$ \forall a, b, c \in \mathbb N , \\ a + b \in \mathbb N \\ \Rightarrow (a+b)^2 \in \mathbb N \\ \Rightarrow a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab \\ c^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab \space\text{ (assumption)}\\ c^2 - \{ (a+b)^2 - ab\} = 0 \\ c = \frac{\pm \sqrt{4((a+b)^2 - 2ab)}}{2} \\ \Rightarrow c = {\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^2 - 2ab}}$$
Now, if I somehow get a way to get natural expression for $c$ instead of irrational number or a complex number, then I can go for the $3$

Thanks :)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг title is correct, i'll try for the power 3, if and only if i know how to do for 2 :)

Comment: The question may be closed, but I'd like to know about your progress in extending the $n=2$ case to the $n=3$ case and see  if you have any progress after a few days. My first comment still holds, except for the last part.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг But, I assume you know what does Informal proof means? It's not proving equivalent to fermat's last theorem.

Comment: See, I understand that the question is not as difficult as FLT itself. However, it is significantly more difficult than the $n=2$ case . If you provide steps and say "these should work out" then I am ok. See, I am very happy to see you attempting this. In fact, I even gave the idea of infinite descent below, to try to guide you. However, the ideas are still long drawn : I should apologize and retract my earlier comment at least for a bad choice of words.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг no problem, never mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, $$(a,b,c)=(3,4,5)$$ because $$3^2+4^2=5^2,$$ but there are infinitely many these triples:

$$(a,b,c)=(2mn,m^2-n^2,m^2+n^2)$$ because
$$(2mn)^2+(m^2-n^2)^2=(m^2+n^2)^2.$$
Check it.

Comment: I didn't vote down, but I want to know how you reach that result.

Comment: +1 for that :), but please derivation

Comment: @MarwanMizuri But, that'd not be algebraically formal proof, as per michael, I knew that thing, but didn't knew the derivation/proof of the mn formula for triplets :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg craked it!, You answered the whole question in one go!

Comment: @Abhas Kumar Sinha The answer on the question with $a^3+b^3=c^3$ is not so easy.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg hmmm....

Comment: @MarwanMizuri Ok.